# Multiple user access to sql database

Tags: c#

I have one master database at server. This contains a table TVehicle information like Make, model, series, grade, production year.
I have multiple users say U1,U2,U3 all have same winforms application (C#) accessing this database from server. I want a logic such that when U1 modify a vehicle say v1, other users u2 & u3 application must show that this vehicle is locked. Please can you help me out in this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using an ORM?

Comment: the simplest way i can think about is to add a column to each row, let's call it ModifiedBy(int) and, and her default value is zero, if U1 changes V1 it ModifiedBy changes to 1, if U2 changes V1 , ModifiedBy changes to 2, and then you check if ModifiedBy is diffrent than zero

Comment: @styx and hope that none forgets to reset that ModifiedBy back to zero when finished. Of course in an ideal world we never forget anything and we never have crashes that stops our processing.

Comment: @Steve I said simplest, not the best way

Comment: OK, but simplest doesn't mean broken.

Comment: never used it but maybe using `ROWLOCK` should help, also @Steve if you have a suggestion i would like to hear

Comment: @styx the OP should look at row version or timestamp for that. If he's using EF that can be implemented easily => https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/handling-concurrency-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Comment: Then, you mean everytime once in certain duration I always keep checking the ModifiedBy bool value to other users? Don't you think it hits performance because everytime we fire query to server for this status?

Answer (score 0):

You can add 3 columns :

ModifiedBy (username )
   ModifiedOn ( DateTime)
   isVehicleLock(Boolean)

to the TVehicle table and check the value of isVehicleLock column everytime you want to display a record, so if "isVehicleLock" is equal to True and ModifiedBy is different from  the current user  you can display the vehicle as locked .

Comment: Then, everytime once in certain duration I always keep checking the ModifiedBy bool value to other users? Don't you think it hits performance because everytime we fire query to server for this status?